# Assign common records the same new Id number

Tags: sql, unique-id

I have a table of 825000 records.  Each record has an ID number.  The Idnumber refers to people and can be in the table more than once.  For example Jon Doe might have a record with a date of 1-1-11 and the Id number 1, Jon Doe might be in there again with a date of 1-1-12 but he will have the same ID number.

I need to de-identify these records and give them a new dummy ID number.  But I need to make sure that people with the same ID number now get the same dummy Id in the new table.

I was going to put all the data into a new table, but how do I ensure that all the records will get the correct new ID number?

Thank you in advance for any help you can give me with this.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: How are you going to generate dummy ids?

Comment: This is MSSQL, I know I could make an identity column, which could generate a new number, but I don't know if there is a way to ensure that people can have the same number while you Identity.